# DAOFactory: return a new instance or always the same?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao, factory-pattern

a simple question that came to my mind:
I have my DAOFactory class:

```
public class DAOFactory {
    public static UserDAO createUserDAO() {
        return new UserDAO();
    }

    public static AdminDAO createUserDAO() {
        return new AdminDAO();
    }
    //etc etc
}
```

Doing this way (which AFAIK is standard), every time someone requests a DAO, a new instance is created.
Actually, there's no need to have more than one instance for each DAO, unless I'm missing something. :D

So, why don't we do like this?

```
public class DAOFactory {
    /* eventually we could use lazy initialization */
    private static UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    private static UserDAO AdminDAO = new AdminDAO();
    //etc etc
    public static UserDAO createUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    public static AdminDAO createUserDAO() {
        return adminDAO;
    }
    //etc etc
}
```

What are the differences between the former and the latter, speaking in terms of performance and memory?
I guess that practically speaking, there are no difference between these two implementations for the clients of DAOFactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically if your DAO classes are immutable, or stateless then you can do it, but if they are not, you must make the DAO classes thread safe, if multiple threads acces the same object and mess with its state, it can create failures.

(In a single threaded environment, what you wrote is acceptable, but when you're writing DAO pattern, I'm sure it's not single threaded)

**So why we don't do it, why isn't it the same: thread safety becomes a concern.**

Comment: This is a good answer, only one thing: do you think that DAO shouldn't be used in a single threaded environment, even in case of relatively simple/small applications? Why?

Comment: I didn't say that, it's debatable. I just said that the DAO pattern is more typical in situations where more users use the same application, and your question contains User and Admin objects (it implicates you have those), so it looks like more users can use it simultaneously, so thread safety is a concern.

edit: the sun developer network defines it as a J2EE pattern, so it's definitely intended for complex multi-user multi-threaded applications.

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html

Comment: It was a generic example :) I think that there may be real-world cases where *one* user deals with lots of persistent data (e.g. a simple ERP maybe?); so in these cases (where DAOs are immutable and thread safety is not an issue) the latter would be a better solution, don't you think?

Comment: This is way DAOs should always be stateless in my opinion, I can't think of anything why it should be stateful.

Comment: @tmh "the latter would be a better solution" - in performance maybe, but creating new DAO instances shouldn't be a bottleneck in your application, especially if they are stateless (no state needed initializing)
BUT, there's one thing you sacrifice: code clarity. If anyone looks at your code, then they see something that looks like a DAO factory, but it isn't one, starts to think whether this way this is thread safe (as they can't know for sure, by seeing only this), and it requires them to think why your code is doing it this way. Implementing the "standard" way brings better code clarity IMHO

Answer (score 1):

If I call a method `create()`, I'd *expect* it to create a new version. Perhaps it's more intuitive to call your method `getInstance()`, which makes no such promises.

Comment: You have  anticipated me: I forgot to ask this about naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends on whether the DAOs have non-global state or not. If they do, using singletons is not advisable.

Besides that, you're creating all the DAOs when accessing the factory in the second approach. If you use it, use some lazy initialization, e.g. double checked locking.

Another point to keep in mind: if you don't need the DAOs a lot (not the case here I guess), they could be garbage collected if you always returned a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot difference between these two implementations. The second one uses state variables that means we can (*or can not*) get some problems in concurrent environment. In fact this depends on specific DAO implementation (*using state or not*).

I prefer first version because it follows the idea of pattern factory. Factory produces something instead of holding something and returning product on demand. Another word for Factory pattern is **virtual constructor**, so as all might expect constructor returns new instance.

Comment: What if my DAOs are stateless?
It seems to me that in this case the second implementation is more suitable and efficient, isn't it?

Comment: Then don't call it DAOFactory as it's not really a factory, just a holder for several static object instances. Call it DAOHolder, or something.

Comment: @tmh Then implement DAOFactory as singleton (*but singleton is a real mess*)

Comment: @szegedi agreed, with that statix instances more suitable names (prefixed with DAO) warehouse, repository, storage :)

Comment: @szegedi I agree, I wouldn't call it DAOFactory if actually it's not a factory :) Just wondering about it's better `DAOFactory` or `DAOHolder`, given your pre-condition (stateless DAOs).